# Background for understanding Measure Theory - preparation

Tags: measure-theory

I've recently come across a dilemma, which I hope I can get some opinion on.

I am currently finishing my undergrad degree in mechanical engineering. I have a great interest in statistics, especially mathematical statistics. There is a graduate program on mathematical statistics with applications, which I am very fond of.

There are many subjects such as modeling in R and similiar, applied stuff, but also some very theoretical subjects - expecialy measure theory and probability topics.

My question is the following: As I have about half a year to prepare, Is it possible for me to obtain sufficient knowledge in mathematics in order to apply and succeed in such a program. I realize I don't have sufficient algebra and real analysis knowledge - knowledge very important to measure theory.

If your answer is yes, what are some specific topics I should start with or which topics should I gain knowledge of first.

Thank you very much.

P.S I am currently going through Rudin and some Algebra, are those O.K?

Comment: Have you studied elementary (non-measure-theoretic) probability?

Comment: Yes, I have studied it.